# Unable to render HTML. Unable to access URL. COM error 800c0019 in FACILITY_INTERNET. The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk

Tags: abcpdf

I am getting the above error message in production when trying to call the AddImageUrl section of ABCPdf (version 10).  This started occurring yesterday just after midday my hosting provider assures me nothing has changed I am the only developer on the project as was working on something else entirely.

The URL provided in the stack trace can be accessed in IE on the web server without any error messages (including SSL).  There is also a UAT environment on the same web server in which the PDF works, the UAT environment is identical in code and application pool settings, the only difference is the web address and database.

The HTML the PDF is calling can take a little time to come up on first load.  Given that data is different I have increased the timeout from 15 seconds to 2 minutes.

I have arranged a reboot to see if that fixes it, but I have run out of things to check.

---

Edit: I did think of one further check, could I add the image of a page not on the site (https://www.google.co.uk/), doing this resulted in the same error so it appears not to be a blocking issue on the worker process.

—
Edit2: switched to the gecko engine and it is now working.

Comment: That is INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE, "Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid".  Pretty basic networking oops, nothing in the question gives us a shot at guessing why this is a problem.

Comment: The certificate is fine and tested independently.  Since trying to pull in the Google home page resulted in the same error I am also confident about the certificate.  Also the certificate chain seems fine since the UAT whilst using a different certificate uses the same provider.  I have temporarily switched to the Gecko engine and that appears to be working.

Comment: If nothing else has changed it sounds like it is a certificate issue. The Chrome engine is way more secure/fussy. Did you check if the hosting instance has the correct time set?

Comment: The hosting instance has the correct time.  Also in addition the instance hosts both UAT and Production, only Production was failing - if there were an SSL time issue I would expect both to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes get this error if the web browser within Abcpdf cant access the URL.

On the webserver add the URLs directly to the local machine hosts file

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

The entry should look something like this

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the first test we ran and the browser could access the page in question.